# Summing numbers like paper with decimal separator

Tags: fractions

Here is my previous [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460078/summing-numbers-like-paper-calculation).

I want to make the same calculations with number with decimal separator. Summing 2, 3 numbers or more.

This is my current code. I want to make 57208 - 57,208; 6207 - 6,207 and more..

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\showsum}[2][c]{%
  $\edef\originalplusmathcode{\the\mathcode`+}%
   \begingroup\lccode`~=`+ \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\\&}%
   \mathcode`+ "8000
  \begin{array}[#1]{@{}r@{\;}r@{}}
   \mathchar\originalplusmathcode& #2 \\
  \hline
  & \the\numexpr#2\relax
  \end{array}%
  $%
 }

\begin{document}

X\quad % to show the baseline

\showsum[b]{57208+6207+12095}\quad
X

\end{document}
```

What I need. Also with 2 numbers only.
\showsum[b]{57,208+6,207+12,095}\quad
[image]

**EDIT**: May question was wrong formulated. I want to sum numbers like that: 6.7+13.12+2.501=22.321 (with comma, not with dot in visualizing). And enter it in function in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is specific to writing a sum and uses [`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)'s `\num` to print the numbers with their thousand separators:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,xfp}

\newcommand{\addsum}[1]{\edef\sumtotal{\inteval{\sumtotal+#1}}}
\newcommand{\stacksum}[1]{\edef\stackedsum{\stackedsum \tnc \tcf{#1} \tnl}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showsum}{ O{c} >{ \SplitList { + } } m }{%
  $\def\stackedsum{}
  \let\tnl\relax\let\tnc\relax\let\tcf\relax
  \ProcessList{#2}{\stacksum}
  \def\tnl{\\}\let\tnc&\def\tcf{\num}
  \sisetup{
    group-separator={,},
    group-minimum-digits=4}
  \begin{array}[#1]{@{} r @{} r @{}}
    +\;{}\stackedsum
    \hline
    & \def\sumtotal{0}%
    \ProcessList{#2}{\addsum}\num{\sumtotal}
  \end{array}$%
}

\begin{document}

X\quad % to show the baseline

\showsum[b]{57208+6207+12095}\quad
X

\end{document}
```

Comment: May question was wrong formulated. I want to sum numbers like that:
6.7+13.12+2.501=22.321 (with comma, not with dot in visualizing). And enter it in function in the same way.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov: For that you can use `\fpeval` (instead of `\inteval` as in my example). If you add `output-decimal-marker={,}` to the setting of `\sisetup`, you'll get a `,` in the output.

Comment: Okay I changed it and it works. https://pastebin.com/uPWt3ABw
But how to make how to make to work with subtraction?

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov: What would you want the input to look like? `\showsub[.]{X-Y-Z-...}`? Or are you ultimately interested in something more generic: `\showsum[.]{X-Y+Z+A-B-C+D...}`?

Comment: How to place the + in the middle in front of 6,207 instead of 57,208. I learned that it's best to be in the center always for better readability.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov: By "in the middle", do you mean the second element? Or do you mean the middle element of the list?

Comment: again you are making the right question. https://imgur.com/a/GgRCaxG .  I mean the middle element of the list.